# jQuery - Método .delay() no para todo el código?

Tags: jquery

Mi objetivo es que al pulsar un botón, un `span` con id "accion" cambie de contenido. Cada vez que esto ocurre, se esconde con `slideUp` y se vuelve a mostrar con el contenido nuevo con `slideDown`.

El problema es que el contenido se cambia al instante, antes de que se esconda. He intentado añadir un delay al `slideUp`, pero el contenido sigue cambiando antes. Éste es el código:

```
function actualizar(){
    $("#accion").slideUp("fast").delay(300);
    $("#accion").html("Datos nuevos van aquí");
    $("#accion").slideDown("fast");
}
```

El resultado es que al llamar a la función, los datos se actualizan en el `span` primero, después se esconde, y por último se vuelve a mostrar. Cuando lo que quiero es que primero se esconda, luego los datos se actualicen y por último se vuelva a mostrar. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El método slideUp te permite añadir como argumento una función a ejecutar una vez completado:

```js
 function actualizar(){
     $("#accion").slideUp(300, function() {
       $("#accion").html("Datos nuevos van aquí");
     });

     $("#accion").slideDown(300);
 }
 
 actualizar();
```

```css
#accion{
  border: solid 1px black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accion">Datos originales</div>
```

Comment: Excelente, solucionado. Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: @MikeSweven Si esta respuesta soluciona tu pregunta, márcala como respuesta aceptada dándole al tick que hay en la parte superior izquierda de la misma

Comment: Mi +1, estaba editando el código y cuando volví vi tu respuesta. Buen trabajo :) al menos ahora tiene dos formas diferentes de hacer el trabajo.

Answer (score 2):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo encadenar las animaciones con una función de callback:

```js
function actualizar(){
  /* Encadenamos slideUp y slideDown, pero como callback de slideUp
    ceramos una función que cambie el valor a mostrar */
  $("#accion")
    .slideUp("fast", function () { $("#accion").html(document.f.datos.value); })
    .slideDown("fast");
  /* Cancelamos el envío del formulario */
  return false;
}
/* Función simple para generar un cambio sencillo */
function azar() {
  document.f.datos.value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000);
}
```

```css
#accion {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px; right: 50px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  font-size: 200%;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="return actualizar()" name="f">
  <input type="text" name="datos" value="Cambiame" />
  <input type="submit" value="Actualizar" />
  <input type="submit" value="Azar" onclick="azar()" />
</form>
<span id="accion"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery tiene métodos que se ejecutan automáticamente (p.e. `addClass` o `html`), otros métodos animados que se ponen en la cola de animación (p.e. `fadeIn` o `slideUp`), y métodos "híbridos"
 que dependiendo de cómo se llamen se ejecutan automáticamente o se mandan a la cola de animación (p.e. `hide` o `show`).

**El [`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) sólo funciona para acciones que están en la cola de animación**. Es por eso que no funciona en tu caso:

1. Ejecutas `slideUp`: se pone en la cola de animación y, como está vacía, se ejecuta automáticamente y acto seguido se pone el `delay(300)` a la cola.
2. Cambias el texto: esta acción no va a la cola de animación por lo que no le afecta el `delay(300)` y se ejecuta inmediatamente.
3. Ejecutas `slideDown`: se pone en la cola de animación, y espera a que terminen las acciones previas (el `slideUp`y el `delay`).

Una vez explicado por qué no funciona, te voy a poner una solución, que **no es mejor que las soluciones que ya tienes**, pero que sirve como alternativa: podrías usar `setTimeout` para forzar que el cambio de texto ocurra "después" de que termine la ejecución de la primera animación, algo como esto:

```
function actualizar(){
    $("#accion").slideUp("fast").delay(300);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#accion").html("Datos nuevos van aquí");
        $("#accion").slideDown("fast");
    }, 300);
}
```